# change IIS port in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, visual-studio-2012, https

I want to change IIS port from 443 to 1443, I set it in this line of applicationhost.confing:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5940:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:144300:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

Then I set project URI in web tab of properties of visual studio to

```
https://localhost:144300/
```

but I have this error when I run my project in visual studio:

```
the local IIS server URL is not a valid URL that includes the protocol (http:// or 
https://). Invalid URI: invalid port specified
```

Comment: Ports can only go to 65535. Lower your port and it should work fine.

Comment: doesn't exist a way to change my port to 1443?

Comment: If you want to change to port 1443 then change `<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:1443:localhost" />` and this `https://localhost:1443/`. Taking a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) might help as well.